# How to isolate a clear relationship from a subset of data with lots of noise and outliers

Tags: regression, clustering, linear-regression

I am doing an analysis of aircraft data and I want to see how much fuel is burnt on landing. There are 2 main factors aircraft type and landing time (ie. time elapsed)

However there is a cheeky third option which is whether or not the pilot used the engines to brake or just the wheel breaks. Simple plot looks like this
[image: time vs fuel by aircraft type]

As you can see there is a very strong straight line on the left between time and fuel plus there are a bunch of points on the right where we can infer that the engine braking has been used.

What I need to do is separate the two events so that for future measurements can say it was an engine break or a wheel break.

I've tried k-means clustering but I just get an arbitrary line at about the 40 mark.

Is there a way to isolate the strong linear relationship so I can then set a rule that would predict if the engine brake was used or not?

Obviously, I can hardcode from the charts, but was interested to know if there was a more elegant way.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have overlapping data, so it is impossible to find a **rule** that would predict if the engine brake was used or not. It is impossible to achieve a recall of 100% with this data. You either need another feature other than fuel used and landing duration, or you have to accept the lower recall. If it is impossible to get more features, you can attempt using a decision tree, but I am afraid that is doing pretty much the same as creating an arbitrary line.

For the features on the leftmost and rightmost you can achieve high accuracy, but because of the overlapping in the middle, you will have low recall. You can also consider having 3 classes: certainly not used engine brake, unsure, and certainly used engine brake. Another option is to use a more complicated model that returns confidence as well as the predicted class.